# Comma Separated string Built In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I used a built in function to create comma separated string using List easily.
(It is not split and join but new function) I'm not able to recollect or find it. If some one knows about it and uses it please post a link to that. Framework - .net 2.0

(It is not Join or split - I know about this, .net has new built in function to create CSV format)

**Check Jacob G Answer below  for what I was looking for let me know your thoughts on it compared to join ;)**

**And whoever gave me -ve rep need to keep some patience and not hurry**

Comment: It was probably an extension method....

Comment: So you want String.Join, but you want it to be called something else?

Comment: Why would you need anything more than String.Join, it's simple and more flexible. Better to understand it, over something that can only join a comma delimited text file.

Comment: I've used LINQ to CSV http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx for heavy lifting with these types of operations.

Comment: in new method you do not have to keep track of last element or count of element, it doesn't only join csv text file i said csv format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you're thinking of...  You need to reference the System.Configuration dll and import the appropriate namespace.

```
    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
    temp.Add("a");
    temp.Add("b");
    temp.Add("c");
    CommaDelimitedStringCollection cdsc = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
    cdsc.AddRange(temp.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(cdsc.ToString());
```

By the way, I found this class by opening up the documentation and typing the word "comma" in the index.

**EDIT**
In response to your new question - Assuming that your List is already constructed, String.Join is going to be more performant.  This collection just uses a StringBuilder.  String.Join has a number of low-level optimization that will make it faster.

(also, not terribly cool to take away the "correct answer" after you change to a new question)

Comment: I didn't take away i wanted it to be open till every one sees it , yours is still correct answer (and i mentioned in question) but people tend to not open questions once they are answered. I will select it back after few hours sorry.

Comment: I also found out that we can directly create csv string instead of using list to create list first  and then comma separated string.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string SomethingElseWithComma(this IEnumerable<string> list)
{
  if(list == null)
      return null;

  return String.Join(",",list.ToArray());
}
```

ps. don't downvote, just having fun.

Comment: you forgot "comma" in your method name ;)

Comment: hey! that must be that method - it sure has comma something in it

Comment: i meant word comma :P and it is new namespace Systems.something
then it gives a function to create csv strings ,
that code is at my home now I'm at work will let you guys know if i find that

Comment: I would be interested in your findings

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, I don't think `List<T>` has any methods or properties which do this. I agree with jsmith it must have been an extension method, etc.

```
//likely the best you'll do without writing your 
//own extension method or coding SomethingElse.
string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the String.Join method?

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(",",yourEnumerable.ToArray())
```